# What does -L mean in ssh on ubuntu?

Tags: ssh, apache2, openssl, port-forwarding

I get this error when I try to connect to my server in Ubuntu to a port other than port 80 (Apache).

```
[-i identity_file] [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address]
```

I added port 8972 to the list of Apache ports on my server

what is **-L** in this code and how i can connect to my server with ssh and **8972** apache2 port?

i tried :: and 0.0.0.0 but i got below errors

```
Bad local forwarding specification '::'
```

and

```
Bad local forwarding specification '0.0.0.0'
```

Comment: `man ssh` hit `/` and type `space`, `+-L` and `Enter`

Comment: We can't really help if you don't show the command you are attempting to run. What you show isn't an error message, it is the part of the default usage message of ssh which is printed when you give it a bad option. So, please [edit] your question and i) add the exact ssh command, ii) tell us how you "added port 8972 to the list of Apache ports", iii) how you "tried :: and 0.0.0.0".

Answer (score 1):

> what is -L in this code

It is the bind address or local socket.

> How can I connect to my server with ssh and 8972 apache2 port?

The [manual](https://manpages.org/ssh) states you need to use one of these 4:

```
-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
-L [bind_address:]port:remote_socket
-L local_socket:host:hostport
-L local_socket:remote_socket
```

In words:

> Specifies that connections to the given TCP port or Unix socket
> on the local (client) host are to be forwarded to the given host
> and port, or Unix socket, on the remote side.  This works by al‐
> locating a socket to listen to either a TCP port on the local
> side, optionally bound to the specified bind_address, or to a
> Unix socket.  Whenever a connection is made to the local port or
> socket, the connection is forwarded over the secure channel, and
> a connection is made to either host port hostport, or the Unix
> socket remote_socket, from the remote machine.